# Display Total under name column and sum of amount under sal column

Tags: sql-server

in a table empno,ename,sal,hiredate is there.
but i want output is

```
empno  ename sal hiredate
122    ganga 2000 1989-02-06
123    reddy 3000 1986-06-02
       Total 5000
```

here empno, hiredate column just empty,no need to display null or zero or anything.

how to write the query in SQL SERVER

Comment: I think you are mixing here some concepts (namely how to write a query and how to display the results).  However, you can easily construct a query with `sum()` and then `UNION ALL` it to the result of the main query.

Comment: This is really something that should be done in the presentation layer, rather than trying to force a query to do it

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Grouping Sets`:

```
select empno
     , coalesce(ename, 'Total') as ename
     , sum(sal) as sall
     , hiredate 
from table1
group by grouping sets ((empno, ename, hiredate),());
```

If ename is nullable this is not sufficient since ename might be null for other reasons than grouping. In that case you can use the `GROUPING` function:

```
select empno
     , case when GROUPING(ename) = 1 
            then 'Total' 
            else ename 
       end as ename
     , sum(sal) as sall
     , hiredate 
from table1
group by grouping sets ((empno, ename, hiredate),());
```

But I agree with @Mark Sinkinson that it is probably better to do this in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

The above comments are absolutely right.

But looking for your question ονε solution is :

```
select empno, ename, sal, hiredate from table1
union all 
select null, 'Total', (select SUM(sal) from table1), null ;
```